# Auto send REVIEW REQUEST email with ACF via Cron Job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a code to auto send booking emails after a booking status is updated. Depending on the booking status, a certain e-mail text is called. This function works perfectly so feel free to use it ;)

```
// Send notification emails to guests
function yl_send_booking_email_after_status_update($post_id) {

    // Get submitted values.
    $values = $_POST['acf'];

    // Check if a specific value was updated.
    if ( isset($_POST['acf']['field_5fbcef66c1d3f']) ) {

        $send_email     = $_POST['acf']['field_5fbcef66c1dce'];
        $booking_status = $_POST['acf']['field_5fbcef66c1d3f'];

        $to = $_POST['acf']['field_5fbcef66c18b8'];

        if ( $send_email == 'yes' &&  $booking_status != 'gesloten' ) {

            if ( $booking_status == 'bevestigd' ) {
                $subject = get_field('booking_email_subject_confirmed', 'booking_settings');
                $message = get_field('booking_email_message_confirmed', 'booking_settings');
            } elseif ( $booking_status == 'gewijzigd' ) {
                $subject = get_field('booking_email_subject_changed', 'booking_settings');
                $message = get_field('booking_email_message_changed', 'booking_settings');
            } elseif ( $booking_status == 'geannuleerd' ) {
                $subject = get_field('booking_email_subject_canceled_by_guest', 'booking_settings');
                $message = get_field('booking_email_message_canceled_by_guest', 'booking_settings');
            } elseif ( $booking_status == 'door ons geannuleerd' ) {
                $subject = get_field('booking_email_subject_canceled_by_us', 'booking_settings');
                $message = get_field('booking_email_message_canceled_by_us', 'booking_settings');
            }

            $headers = array
            (
                'From: ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>',
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
                'MIME-Version: 1.0',
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
            );
            $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        }

    }

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'yl_send_booking_email_after_status_update', 5);
```

Now I want to chanllange myself a bit further. I want to auto send (via cron job) a 'Review request' email 'X hours' after the booking date/time. But I'm stuck for a while now.

Emails do get send but only with pre text. The actuall content of the booking (name, date, time, etc) is left blank.

When I use `$post_id` in the function, no emails are being send. I hope I made myself a bit clear.

Here's what I have:

```
// Send review emails to guests
function yl_send_review_email_function($post_id) {

    // Get submitted values.
    $values = $_POST['acf'];

    $send_email     = $_POST['acf']['field_5fbcef66c1dce'];
    $booking_status = $_POST['acf']['field_5fbcef66c1d3f'];
    $review_delay   = get_field('booking_settings_review_delay', 'booking_settings');

    $to             = 'some@email.com';

    $subject = get_field('booking_email_subject_review', 'booking_settings');
    $message = get_field('booking_email_message_review', 'booking_settings') . '<br /><br />' . $send_email . '<br /><br />' . $booking_status . ' dit no ' . $review_delay;

    $headers = array
        (
        'From: ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>',
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
    );
    $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

    $status = 'gesloten';
    update_field( 'booking_status', $status );

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'yl_send_review_email_function', 5);




// Time schedule for Cron Job Event
function yl_cron_schedules($schedules){
    if(!isset($schedules["1min"])){
        $schedules["1min"] = array(
            'interval' => 1*60,
            'display' => __('Once every minute')
        );
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["5min"])){
        $schedules["5min"] = array(
            'interval' => 5*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes')
        );
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["30min"])){
        $schedules["30min"] = array(
            'interval' => 30*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 30 minutes')
        );
    }
    return $schedules;
}




// Schedule Cron Job Event
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('yl_booking_review_mailer')) {
      //You can now use '5min', '20min' or any of the default here
      wp_schedule_event( time(), '1min', 'yl_booking_review_mailer' );
  }

  add_action( 'yl_booking_review_mailer', 'yl_send_review_email_function' );
```

PS. I left the needed IF STATEMENTS out to be sure that's nog stopping emails going out.

Comment: `$values = $_POST['acf'];` - that's probably not getting you much, when you execute this as a cron job.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how should I get the values instead?

Comment: When you execute this as a cron, you are outside of any post context. So you would probably need to start with a database query that _fetches_ all the relevant posts first of all. And then loop over them, to check your criteria.